# append option to select - jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i use jquery to append options to select with these **classes** and **id**
But when I use this **class** (`form-control selectpicker` ), my code does **not** work

***select element :***

```html
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="lessonsDD">
</select>
```

jquery Ajax :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LinksManager/GetLessons",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
      //console.log(res);
      $.each(res, function(index, value) {
        $("#lessonsDD").append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.lessonName + '</option>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

But it works when I delete the class!!

how can i fix it ?

Comment: _"when I use this class (`form-control selectpicker`)"_... when you use it **where**? If you intend to select the element by its classes with jQuery, you'd want `$(".form-control.selectpicker")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="lessonsDD">
</select>
```

The issue related the `selectpicker` class. From the above code, I assume you are using the bootstrap-select package, right?

From the `bootstrap-select` official document, we can see that add the `selectpicker` class to the select elements, it will auto-initialize `bootstrap-select`.

[image]

Since the select element's options is dynamically added, after adding the select options, you should use the JavaScript method to call the bootstrap-select.

So, please modify your code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LinksManager/GetLessons",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
      //console.log(res);
      $.each(res, function(index, value) {
        $("#lessonsDD").append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.lessonName + '</option>');
      });
      $('#lessonsDD').selectpicker();
    }
  });
});
```

The result as below (test it in an Asp.net 5 application):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help :)